# What does vga=844 means and what other values are there?

Tags: 8.1-oreo, android-x86, virtualbox

I installed Android-x86 on VirtualBox and find the resolution to be too big, because it causes lags on the virtual device. I wanted to try a smaller resolution and came to the `menu.lst` file with the `vga=844` kernel option.

I tried to look around for a list of valid values, but can't find much information.

So, what other VGA values are there?

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/svga.rst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers) below lists some Linux vide mode numbers.

[image: IMG:]

As stated [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/vesafb.txt):

> The mode you wish to use is derived from the
>   VESA mode number. Here are those VESA mode numbers:

```
  | 640x480  800x600  1024x768 1280x1024

----+-------------------------------------
256 |  0x101    0x103    0x105    0x107   
32k |  0x110    0x113    0x116    0x119   
64k |  0x111    0x114    0x117    0x11A   
16M |  0x112    0x115    0x118    0x11B
```

> The video mode number of the Linux kernel is the VESA mode number plus
>   0x200.
>
> Linux_kernel_mode_number = VESA_mode_number + 0x200
>
> So the table for the Kernel mode numbers are:

```
    | 640x480  800x600  1024x768 1280x1024
----+-------------------------------------
256 |  0x301    0x303    0x305    0x307   
32k |  0x310    0x313    0x316    0x319   
64k |  0x311    0x314    0x317    0x31A   
16M |  0x312    0x315    0x318    0x31B
```

Comment: Very informative, thanks!